# expected error when flipping bits of binary string

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expectation

Assume we have a binary string with $n$ bits. Now we flip $k$ (different) bits and get a new binary string. For any [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) the two binary strings represent integers $x$ and $x'$.

What is the expected error $|x-x'|$?

Any idea how to calculate this? I'am interested in an analytical answer depending on $n$ and $k$. I'am not interested in approximation or a correct answer for small values by write force.

**Update:** So I thought a bit more about this problem and I think the following is true. Let $M = \{0,\dots , 2^n-1\}$ and $\pi\colon M \rightarrow M$ a bijection. Then $$\sum_{x,x'\in M, d(x,x') = k} |\pi(x) - \pi(x')| = \sum_{x,x'\in M, d(x,x') = k} |x - x'|.$$
where $d(x,x')$ denotes the hamming distance. I haven't proved this, but letting $\pi$ be the above mentioned Gray code, this seems to be numerically correct. Computing the expected error when flipping $k$ bits is not so difficult anymore. I think it should be 
$$\frac{k}{n\cdot{n-1 \choose k-1}} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2^i {i\choose k-1}.$$

Comment: For an exact analytical calculation one needs to calculate the probability of all error patterns and calculate distortion by averaging the absolute errors. It is straightforward If the number of error patterns is not so high. Otherwise, either use simulations or approximate.

Comment: I already simulated it, but I am interested in finding the axact analytical answer.

Comment: @math635 Of course you want a formula, but having the exact numbers for small $n$ really helps. 1. You can look for a pattern in the numbers to find a formula. 2. If you think you found a formula, you can easily check if it's right. If you can add a table of rational numbers for $n$ up to 8 or something and every $k$, would be great.

Comment: @math635 I assume that bits can't be switched and then switched back again?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: The update equation looks false, let $\pi$ send even values $x$ to $x+2$ and odd values $y$ to $y$, all mod $2^n$. For $k=1, n=2$ the RHS is: $$|0-1| + |0-2| + |1-0| + |1-3| + |2-0| + |2-3| + |3-1| + |3-2| = 12$$
LHS:
$$|2-1| + |2-0| + |1-2| + |1-3| + |0-2| + |0-3| + |3-1| + |3-0| = 16$$

If the second sum were over $x,x'$ with $d(\pi(x), \pi(x')) = k$ you'd be fine, but that isn't helpful. If $\pi$ preserved hamming distance you'd be fine. Perhaps if $\pi$ is a gray code as well?

Comment: After looking at Chris' answer we see that simply $\frac{k}{n \cdot \binom{n-1}{k-1}} = \frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}}$ for $1 \le k \le n$

Comment: yes true. I derived the formula in a more complicated way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ideas proposed in the update are correct. First, we can show

$$\displaystyle\mathbb{E}_{x, x' \in M, d(x, x') = k} |{\pi(x) - \pi(x')}| = \mathbb{E}_{x, x' \in M, d(x, x') = k} |x - x'|$$

where $M = \{0, \dots, 2^n - 1\}$ and $\pi$ is the **inverse** Gray code i.e. decoding function (actually, both work, but I think your claim flips codeword bits, not plaintext bits). I did it by induction, but it would be nice if there was a slick counting argument:

$$\displaystyle\mathbb{E}_{x, x' \in M, d(x, x') = k} |{\pi(x) - \pi(x')}| = p_{00}\mathbb{E}_{x, x' \in M, d(x, x') = k, x_1 = x'_1 = 0} |\pi(x) - \pi(x')| + p_{01}\mathbb{E}_{x, x' \in M, d(x, x') = k, x_1 \neq x'_1} |\pi(x) - \pi(x')| + p_{11}\mathbb{E}_{x, x' \in M, d(x, x') = k, x_1 = x'_1 = 1} |\pi(x) - \pi(x')|$$

where $p_{00}, p_{01}, p_{11}$ are some constants and $x_1, x'_1$ denote the first bits of $x, x'$. A critical property of the Gray code is that $\pi$ restricts to the Gray code on $\{0, \dots, 2^{n-1} - 1\}$. Thus the induction hypothesis covers the $p_{00}$ term (and similarly the $p_{11}$ term).

For the $p_{01}$ case, WLOG we've picked $x$ from $\{0, \dots, 2^{n-1} - 1\}$ and $x'$ from $\{2^{n-1}, \dots, 2^{n} - 1\}$. This guarantees that $\pi(x')$ is greater than $\pi(x)$, and so conditioning on this case

$$\mathbb{E}|\pi(x') - \pi(x)| = \mathbb{E}[\pi(x')] - \mathbb{E}[\pi(x)] = 2^{n-1} = \mathbb{E}|x' - x|$$

This completes the induction. Now we can straightforwardly compute the expectation

$$\mathbb{E}_{x, x' \in M, d(x, x') = k} |x - x'| = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2^i \frac{i \choose k-1}{n \choose k} $$

The probabilistic experiment that samples $|x- x'|$ is equivalent to the following: select $k$ (distinct) indices out of $\{0, 1, \dots, n-1\}$, and call them $i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k$. These are the bits on which $x$ and $x'$ differ. Pick a random sign $s_j \in \{\pm 1\}$ for each, and then output $|s_12^{i_1} + s_22^{i_2} + \cdots + s_k 2^{i_k}|$.

The key observation here is that the sign of $s_12^{i_1} + s_22^{i_2} + \cdots + s_k 2^{i_k}$ is determined by $2^{i_k}$, because the other terms cannot overpower it. So
$$|s_12^{i_1} + s_22^{i_2} + \cdots + s_k 2^{i_k}| = 2^{i_k} + s_12^{i_1} + s_22^{i_2} + \cdots + s_{k-1} 2^{i_{k-1}}$$
Now when we take the expectation, we can use linearity. All terms except the first disappear, and we're left with
$$\mathbb{E}_{x, x' \in M, d(x, x') = k} |x - x'| = \mathbb{E}[2^{i_k}]$$
Finally, the probability that $i$ is the maximum of $k$ choices from $\{0, \dots, n-1\}$ is $\binom{i}{k-1} \left/\binom{n}{k}\right.$, as we must pick $k-1$ smaller elements from $\{0, 1, \dots, i-1\}$, a set of size $i$. This shows
$$\mathbb{E}_{x, x' \in M, d(x, x') = k} |x - x'| = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2^i \frac{i \choose k-1}{n \choose k} $$

Comment: Ah the induction is nice. I am only wondering: is this property that a gray code $\pi^{-1} : M \rightarrow M$ restricts to a map $\{0,\dots , 2^{n-1}-1\} \rightarrow \{0,\dots , 2^{n-1}-1\}$ always true, or just for the gray code given by $\pi(x) = x \oplus (x >> 1)$? Also it would be interesting to find all permutations that don't change the exppectet error(or at least some nice condition which implies that the expected error doesn't change).

Comment: The induction here really seems to require that $\pi$ have the "recursive by 2" property, that $\pi$ (1) restricts to a bijection on the two halves of its domain and (2) on the two halves of its domain, $\pi$ is self-similar. This kind of makes sense for a question about bit flips/Hamming weight, though.

Comment: There are two "normal" functions $\pi$ with the same expected error: the standard Gray code and the identity function. You *can* build more functions with the same expected error: on any dyadic intervals $[c\cdot 2^k, (c+1) \cdot 2^{k})$, you can swap out the gray code for the identity function or vice versa. This works because (1) the Gray code is bijective on every dyadic interval and (2) the induction above extends to show the expected error from $x$ in an interval is the same for these two functions.
I suspect this captures all of the functions with the same error.

Comment: Also(trivially) shifting mod 2^n will work, i.e. $\pi(x) = x + y \mod (2^n-1)$ for some fixed $y$.

Comment: Pretty sure this only works for $y = 2^{n-1}$ (my computer program told me it's different for e.g. $y = 2, n=3, k = 1$).

Comment: but shouldn't it then just cancel out: $|\pi(x)-\pi(x')| = |x+y-(x'+y)| = |x-x'|$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62331/discussion-between-chris-jones-and-math635).

Answer (score 0):

My first thought when I was presented this question was one of well-definedness. You only give me n and k, but shouldn't the result depend on $x$, the binary string, as well? Nope - it doesn't. I haven't tried to prove this, but it seems true given the case $n=3, k=1$ $x \in \{000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111\}$. If we examine $x=000$, $x=010$ and $x=101$.

Case 1: $x = 000$

Possible new strings, $x' \in \{001,010,100\}$

$<|x-x'|>= \frac{|001-000|+|010-000|+|100-000|}{3}$ = $\frac{100+010+001}{3} = 1*\Sigma_{i=0}^{n-1}2^i/\binom{n}{k} = \frac{7}{3}$

Case 2: $x = 010$

Possible new strings, $x' \in \{011,000,110\}$

$<|x-x'|>= \frac{|011-010|+|000-010|+|110-010|}{3}$ = $\frac{100+010+001}{3} = 1*\Sigma_{i=0}^{n-1}2^i/\binom{n}{k} = \frac{7}{3}$

Case 3: $x = 101$

$x' \in \{001,111,100\}$

$<|x-x'|>= \frac{|001-101|+|111-101|+|100-101|}{3}$ = $\frac{100+010+001}{3} = 1*\Sigma_{i=0}^{n-1}2^i/\binom{n}{k} = \frac{7}{3}$

This result makes sense as changing the $j^{th}$ digit of a binary number changes its value the same amount no matter what that number is. Also, now that we know the problem is well-defined, we can pick any $x$ (as long as it has $n$ binary digits) and the result will be the same as any other $x$. An easy $x$ to pick is all zeroes. This way, we reduce the problem to the expected value of an n-digit binary number with k ones (since $|x-x'|=x'$ when $x=0$). And now we can easily apply elementary counting to solve it.

If there are $k$ ones in the string (with all other digits zero), in all of the strings of size $n$, each digit will be flipped a total of $k$ times. Then the error caused by flipping the $i^{th}$ digit is $2^i$ (where the one's place is indexed as $0$). So the sum of error for all the strings will be $\Sigma_{i=0}^{n-1}k2^i = k\Sigma_{i=0}^{n-1}2^i$. And the total number of strings is just n choose k since you are choosing k of the n digits to flip. This leads me to the final result of $$k\Sigma_{i=0}^{n-1}2^i/\binom{n}{k} = \frac{k(2^{n}-1)}{\binom{n}{k}}$$ Note: this formula is why I included a $1*$ in some of the above formulas for the specific case $n=3$, $k=1$ - the $1$ was supposed to make you think of $k$.

Can anyone who wrote a script to calculate this confirm that this analytic result matches some of their numerical results?

Comment: I tested the formulas of OP and Chris, those formulas give the same numbers as brute force. Your final formula gives different numbers.